# Will Google Tag Manager work without <body> part of code?

Tags: google-tag-manager

When installing Google Tag Manager I have to add 2 code snippets into my website: one into the `<head>` section and the other in the `<body>` section. The website CMS I'm using (Teachable) doesn't give me access to the `<body>` section, only the `<header>`.

Is there a way to install Google Tag Manager properly without access to the `<body>`?

I tried putting both code snippets in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<body>` part is not needed.

The `<body>` part is just a `<noscript>` part of GTM. GTM is a js framework. The only thing `<noscript>` helps with is loading only pixel type tags when client has js disabled.

But people don't have js disabled. Also, it's likely that your site doesn't work when JS is disabled. Also, at the point when JS is indeed disabled, firing pixels is very likely the least of your concerns. Noscript is the remnant from the past, effectively.

I normally never install the noscript part of GTM.

Comment: Makes sense. I have a react application so there is basically no point to installing the noscript part since the site wouldn't be working anyways..